# Cannot get PHP to work on IIS web server

Tags: php, iis, webserver

I cannot figure out how to get PHP to work with IIS web server.  Currently when I try to load a php page, I get the following message
HTTP Error 500.21 - Internal Server Error
Handler "PHP52_via_FastCGI" has a bad module "FastCgiModule" in its module list
This is what I did,
Went to
http://www.microsoft.com/web/platform/phponwindows.aspx
clicked on install (seemed like it worked).
But, I cannot get my php pages to work!
Ted

Answer (score 9):

You probably don't have the CGI module for IIS installed.  Open up the Microsoft Web Installer again.  Look in the server section of IIS: CGI and install it.

For completeness, you can check your installed modules by opening up the Internet Information Services Manager.  Expand the Sites to your default website (or other site if you have another setup).  In the IIS section, look for and open up Modules.  If you don't see FastCgiModule, then you'll have to install that via the Web Installer (looks like it's bundled with the regular Cgi Module).

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable CGI support in IIS.  This is not enabled by default and is one of the options in "Windows Features" when choosing to install IIS.  See here for instructions on how to enable it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/install.windows.iis7.php

The MS Web Installer does not turn this on for you.

Answer (score 2):

I also did not have the CGI Module installed, however I did have IIS already installed

This worked for me...

Open PowerShell as an admin

```bash
Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CGI
```

You should get an output similar to this:

```bash
PS C:\> Enable-WindowsOptionalFeature -Online -FeatureName IIS-CGI                                      

Path          :
Online        : True
RestartNeeded : False
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

- IIS->Handler Mappings->Add Module Mapping
- Request path: *.php
- Module: FastCgiModule
- Executable: C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe (depends where php is installed)
- Name: WhatEverYouWannaCallIt
- OK
- YES